# Unable to change input date format in angular using input type date

Tags: angular, date, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 10 with bootstrap 4. I want to change input type date format from(dd/mm/yyyy) to DD/MM/YYYY. But its not working.

Here is my angular code

```
<input type="date" id="controlKey" class="form-control" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY" />
```

[image: Shows like this]

But I need to display as below(DD/MM/YYYY). I don't need the placeholder but need date input like bootstrap

[image: As displayed below]

I am not sure where I was doing wrong. Please suggest

I got code from here [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mc5zsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). It would be helpful if dd/mm/yyyy changes to DD / MM / YYYY

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: @NamanJain I got code from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mc5zsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This is the closest you can get with `<input type="date">` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlzcv6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I would recommend using material datepicker along with *ngIf

Comment: @NamanJain We currently use bootstrap and doing the same way as you mentioned in typescript. But, they need DD/MM/YYYY to be static on click/focus....

Comment: Then use bootstrap datepicker. The disadvantages of a native datepicker is that you have a lot less control. There are no hooks to control the look of the date picker; you get what the browser wants to give you. You also have a lot less control over the behaviour.

Comment: Same issue with bootstrap date picker. I was unable to change dd/mm/yyyy to DD/MM/YYYY @NamanJain

Comment: Not sure how you added bootstrap datepicker to your project. Hope this will be helpful https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-s7nupr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @NamanJain I want type to be date and not text and we dont have a date picker(Removed styles for icon). User will type date

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Using Angular You Can Use Date picker
[Date Picker](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/datepicker/overview#nbdatepickerdirective)